# Filter NULL columns in in MySQL result

Tags: python, mysql, null

I built a small python API which should return a JSON filled with all necessary key / value pairs. The key values are just queried from a MySQL DB like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM flowers 
WHERE favourite = 1
```

Output:

```
id        color     size     favourite  ...
---------------------------------------------
1234      yellow    big      1          ...
1235      <null>    small    1          ...
1236      blue      <null>   1          ...
1237      <null>    <null>   1          ...
```

Executing this query will return an array which looks similar to this:

```
[
    {'id': 1234, 'color': "yellow", 'size': "big", 'favourite': 1, ... },
    {'id': 1234, 'color': "<null>", 'size': "small", 'favourite': 1, ... },
    {'id': 1234, 'color': "blue", 'size': "<null>", 'favourite': 1, ... },
    {'id': 1234, 'color': "<null>", 'size': "<null>", 'favourite': 1, ... }
]
```

In order to prevent sending any useless entries to the clients, I'd like to choose what I'm SELECTing. My goal is to keep selecting each row where `favourite=1`, but just leave away the column, returning `<null>`. So I get a result equal to this:

```
[
    {'id': 1234, 'color': "yellow", 'size': "big", 'favourite': 1, ... },
    {'id': 1234, 'size': "small", 'favourite': 1, ... },
    {'id': 1234, 'color': "blue", 'favourite': 1, ... },
    {'id': 1234, 'favourite': 1, ... }
]
```

I'm also very interested in the performance. Is it possible / worth to reach my target via the MySQL query or is it better to select also the `<null>` results and filter them with a custom python method afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter columns in SQL, because the columns are specified in the `SELECT` clause, and all rows have the same columns. You'll have to do it in PHP, by looping over the columns when adding them to the result array.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result_row = array();
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        if ($value !== null) {
            $result_row[$col] = $value;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $result_row;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. In my case I use python but the principle is the same.

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't read the tags. Maybe you should convert this to Python and post your code, so you can accept a proper answer.